# How to change BadgeText from background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Total newbie here.

I'm trying to create a very simple chrome extension. Its main functionality is to change its BadgeText depending on some API endpoint response. I want to check the endpoint every 5 seconds so I want to run it in the background. Here is what I've got:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "BusyIndicator",
  "description": "busy indicator",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": ["background.js"],
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": []
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BusyIndicator</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>nothing here yet</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js` is just an empty file right now

`background.js`:

```
setInterval(function() {
  fetch('https://toiletbusy.herokuapp.com/')
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.json.busy == false) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'BUSY'});
      } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'FREE'});
      };
    });
}, 5000);
```

I tried different things but it looks like background.js is not getting executed at all (e.g. `console.log` does not log anything)

Comment: Open the background page devtools and you should see an error about the URL being forbidden. You need to add `"https://toiletbusy.herokuapp.com/"` in "permissions" in manifest.json and reload the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm it does not throw any errors. Added this url anyway.
I tried to add `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'FREE'});` before `setInterval` and it doesn't work either so it looks like `background.js` is not executed at all.

Comment: Ah indeed, you need `{ "scripts": ["background.js"] }` in "background". Make sure you don't invent stuff - simply copypaste from the documentation :-)

Comment: @wOxxOm nice, thank you! You can add it as an answer if you want